# How to ensure that TensorFlow saves the average loss across the whole dataset in a training loop written from scratch

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorboard

I am training my conditional GAN network using the code from TensorFlow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix)  that uses a written from scratch training loop

```
def fit(train_ds, epochs, test_ds):
  for epoch in range(epochs):
    start = time.time()

    display.clear_output(wait=True)

    for example_input, example_target in test_ds.take(1):
      generate_images(generator, example_input, example_target)
    print("Epoch: ", epoch)

    # Train
    for n, (input_image, target) in train_ds.enumerate():
      print('.', end='')
      if (n+1) % 100 == 0:
        print()
      train_step(input_image, target, epoch)
    print()

    # saving (checkpoint) the model every 20 epochs
    if (epoch + 1) % 20 == 0:
      checkpoint.save(file_prefix = checkpoint_prefix)

    print ('Time taken for epoch {} is {} sec\n'.format(epoch + 1,
                                                        time.time()-start))
  checkpoint.save(file_prefix = checkpoint_prefix)
```

and the train step is defined like this

```
@tf.function
def train_step(input_image, target, epoch):
  with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
    gen_output = generator(input_image, training=True)

    disc_real_output = discriminator([input_image, target], training=True)
    disc_generated_output = discriminator([input_image, gen_output], training=True)

    gen_total_loss, gen_gan_loss, gen_l1_loss = generator_loss(disc_generated_output, gen_output, target)
    disc_loss = discriminator_loss(disc_real_output, disc_generated_output)

  generator_gradients = gen_tape.gradient(gen_total_loss,
                                          generator.trainable_variables)
  discriminator_gradients = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss,
                                               discriminator.trainable_variables)

  generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(generator_gradients,
                                          generator.trainable_variables))
  discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(discriminator_gradients,
                                              discriminator.trainable_variables))

  with summary_writer.as_default():
    tf.summary.scalar('gen_total_loss', gen_total_loss, step=epoch)
    tf.summary.scalar('gen_gan_loss', gen_gan_loss, step=epoch)
    tf.summary.scalar('gen_l1_loss', gen_l1_loss, step=epoch)
    tf.summary.scalar('disc_loss', disc_loss, step=epoch)
```

now my **question** is for the summary writer is it saving the loss of the batch only or the average across the whole dataset and if it is for the batch which batch loss is it saving and how can I get the average across the whole dataset if the batches are not the same size ?
I assumed it was the average because I got the code from a tensorflow tutorial so I trusted it but when I think about it I am not sure that that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Tensorboard to get only the loss per epoch, you need to save the values to Tensorboard at the end of every epoch, not at every batch.

First, create variables for mean values for every epoch:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    mean_epoch_loss = tf.metrics.Mean()
    # etc...
```

And in `train_step`, update this value with the corresponding loss:

```
@tf.function
def train_step(input_image, target, epoch):
    # etc...
    mean_epoch_loss.update_state(epoch_loss)
```

And at the end of every epoch, save this value to Tensorboard:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    # etc...
    with summary_writer.as_default():
        tf.summary.scalar('mean_epoch_loss', mean_epoch_loss, step=epoch)
```